# Filling NA in a data frame with a specified rule in R

Tags: r

Let I have such a date frame(df1) with column name x:

```
df1<-as.data.frame(x=c(4,3,2,16,7,8,9,1,12))
colnames(df1)<-"x"
df1[2,1]<-NA
df1[3,1]<-NA
df1[4,1]<-NA
```

The output is:

```
> df1
   x
1  4
2 NA
3 NA
4 NA
5  7
6  8
7  9
8  1
9 12
```

I want to add a column to the data frame. The new column(y) will fill NA's with the nearest value above the first NA above.

The code and the output is(that is what I want)

```
df1$y<-na.locf(df1, fromLast = FALSE)

> df1
   x  x
1  4  4
2 NA  4
3 NA  4
4 NA  4
5  7  7
6  8  8
7  9  9
8  1  1
9 12 12
```

Note:I didn't understand why the second column's name is "x" alhough I defined it as "y".

However, above method gives error naturally when the first entry is NA as below:

```
df2<-as.data.frame(c(4,3,2,16,7,8,9,1,12))
colnames(df2)<-"x"
df2[1,1]<-NA
df2[2,1]<-NA
df2[3,1]<-NA

> df2
   x
1 NA
2 NA
3 NA
4 16
5  7
6  8
7  9
8  1
9 12
```

When I apply the below code:

```
df2$y<-na.locf(df2, fromLast = FALSE)
```

I get the below error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = list(x = c(16, 7, 8, 9,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 9
```

In such situations I just want to the oppsite of `na.locf(df2, fromLast  =FALSE)`. Namely fill NA's as the first value of below NA.

Desired output is:

```
  x  y
1 NA 16
2 NA 16
3 NA 16
4 16 16
5  7  7
6  8  8
7  9  9
8  1  1
9 12 12
```

So using tryCatch function, I wrote the below code:

```
df2$y<-tryCatch(na.locf(df2, fromLast = FALSE),
                error=function(err)
                  {na.locf(df2, fromLast = TRUE)})
```

However, I got such an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = list(x = c(16, 7, 8, 9,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 9
```

So in summary the problem is:

- if the data frame's first entry is not NA,then fill the NA with first element above
- if the data frame's first entry is NA, then fill the NA with first element below.

How can I this using R? Especially with tryCatch function? I also don't understnad why the second column's name seem as "x" instead of "y"?

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a double `na.locf` with the first one having the option `na.rm = FALSE`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(na.locf(df2, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE)
#  x
#1 16
#2 16
#3 16
#4 16
#5  7
#6  8
#7  9
#8  1
#9 12
```

---

If we want to have two columns

```
transform(df2, y = na.locf(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))
#   x  y
#1 NA 16
#2 NA 16
#3 NA 16
#4 16 16
#5  7  7
#6  8  8
#7  9  9
#8  1  1
#9 12 12
```

NOTE: Make sure to assign it to a new object or to the same object i.e. `df2 <- transform(...`

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun. That is very clever way.

Comment: One last question why th new column's name is "x" insted of "y"

Comment: @oercim Because we are applying the `na.locf` on the dataset and not on a single column.  It returns the original dataset.  Suppose if we do `transform(df2, y = na.locf(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: Ok @akrun. Thanks a lot.